# Excel Multiple find and replace

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have `C2:F2` in sheet1 they should be find from all cell of sheet2
then replace `C13:F13` values in sheet1 with all cells of sheet2 that have same value

Then I need to know how much value changed in any value

Sheet2:
![Sheet2][2]

I've attached a GIF for a good understanding:

[GIF][3]

It's very good and useful for my work but I want to know can we have some modification on it?

1-in beside of T1220 cells , when don't find any number , automatically delete the IPs
Can we change the code that doesn't delete the IPs when doesn't find any IP in Sheet2

2-Can we did something that doesn't change the values of selected cells after pressing the button?

3-is there any way to undo after pressing the button ?
undo doesn't work after pressing the button

Sorry for many questions

I can send you the original of this Excel file as a private message
but its not able to send a private message in this portal

Comment: It's certainly possible to do. Although it's not 100% clear exactly what you want to achieve. An example picture and one with expected result would help for a more complete answer.

Comment: dear Cristofer
thanks for your reply
i attached the pictures

Comment: Dear @Cristofer , is it possible to have thist output with VBA codes ?

Comment: I'm still not all that clear on what you need. If you could do sheet 2 into more of an "easy" example, and then show the desired output in a new image, because I'm not sure what you mean with "number of changes".

Comment: aboute number of changes : quantity of changes
for example how many IPs finded from C2 thats exist in sheet2
im recording my scrren and change an IP for example 
i will share it here 5 min later

Comment: Gif file hyperlink attached for best understanding

Comment: Dear @Cristofer , did you inderstand what i mean ?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want to do. The find and replace part is easy enough, unfortunately running it in VBA does not return the number of changes. Looking for good solution to that.

Comment: Dear @ChristoferWeber thanks to you this Macro is working for me well, but i need to add an option, an example for replacing 10.193.124.1 ip with 10.193.124.234 all the ips in Sheet2 that have .1 in last digit will change to my requested ip, ex: 10.193.124.10 or 10.193.124.11 is exist in Sheet2 and will replace with 10.193.124.234, how i can revised the code to avoid this mistake ? i want to replace only 10.193.124.1 , not all the IPs that last digit is starting with .1 value i wiant to find exact math , like Match whole word only option in Notepad++ find and replace

Comment: Dear @ChristoferWeber would you please advice ?, ireally need that and any one doesnt know how to do that ?

Comment: Dear @ChristoferWeber hop you are well , how i can add Match whole word funtion to this code ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, It's been very busy this close to Christmas. For the `.replace` method, there is a `LookAt` parameter. So if you change the row `c.replace What:=find_me, Replacement:=replace_with` to `c.Replace What:=find_me, Replacement:=replace_with, LookAt:=xlWhole` it should only look at the whole IP, and not change parts of it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, using "Find and replace" in VBA is very simple, we use Range.Replace()

```
Range.Replace (What, Replacement, LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat, ReplaceFormat)
```

So, to search an entire worksheet, we can do something like:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells.replace What:=Range("A2"), Replacement:=Range("B2")
```

To replace everything in the first sheet matching the value of `A2`with the value of `B2`.
However, we do not know how many values are changed.

By using the `.find()` method, we can find each entry, count it, and move on to the next one.

What I've done is two subs, one that finds and replaces, and one that defines what should be found and replaced.

It currently changes what is selected, and is also dependent on cells being exactly where they are in the example picture, so you might want to edit a bit.

```
Option Explicit
Sub run()
Dim cell As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cell In Selection ' Select what cells you want to use
            Call CountReplace(cell, cell.Offset(8), 2) 'Replace with cell 8 cells down, and on sheet number 2
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub CountReplace(ByVal find_me As Range, replace_with As Range, dataSheet As Long)
Dim c As Range, i As Long
If find_me = replace_with Then Exit Sub 'Skip if the numbers are the same
i = 0
With Worksheets(dataSheet).UsedRange
    Set c = .find(find_me, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Do
            c.replace What:=find_me, Replacement:=replace_with 'The find and replace function
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            i = i + 1 'Counting how many times we find something
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With
find_me = replace_with 'Replace the searched number with the replaced value
find_me.Offset(1) = i 'Store the number in the cell below the selected cell
End Sub
```

[image]

It does have at least one flaw. If multiple entries exist in the same cell, we will find the first one, but replace all, so they will only count as one.
So if that's a problem, then you'll have to figure that one out.

Comment: Dear @ChristoferWeber thanks to you this Macro is working for me well, but i need to add an option, an example for replacing 10.193.124.1 ip with 10.193.124.234 all the ips in Sheet2 that have .1 in last digit will change to my requested ip, ex: 10.193.124.10 or 10.193.124.11 is exist in Sheet2 and will replace with 10.193.124.234, how i can revised the code to avoid this mistake ? i want to replace only 10.193.124.1 , not all the IPs that last digit is starting with .1 value

i wiant to find exact math , like Match whole word only option in Notepad++ find and replace

Comment: Nice & useful also .. +10 ☺